# How to show matplotlib charts in browser (html)?

Tags: matplotlib

I need to open a bar charts in Matplotlib in a browser-Like Firefox- but I shouldn't use Bokeh in my Project. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Use the WebAgg backend, which opens a browser window with the plot and is fully interactive like the Qt or GTK window.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('WebAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# do your plotting
plt.show()
```

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.random.random(100)
>>> b=np.random.random(100)
>>> plt.plot(a,b)
```

Opens `http://127.0.0.1:8988/` showing:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

IPython with `%matplotlib inline` as demonstrated [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%203%20-%20Plotting%20with%20Matplotlib.ipynb)